# Having and issue with queryRequest in AWS Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having an issue with dynamodb and the QueryRequest. I want to implement paging with dynamodb.

I am getting an error back from postman. Scroll right for full error.

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-06-04T00:12:42.526+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException",
"message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: TDAUFVG205A11TFDGOD9U53MMBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)",
```

My project does connect and work fine with other api's gets. dynamoDBMapper.query works fine and does return data.

The problem is from the new code using QueryRequest.

```
public String getRequestPage(String query,  String lastEvaluatedKey, String limit) {

...
Map<String, AttributeValue> mapLastEvaluatedKey = null;

Map<String,String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributesNames.put("#tagId","tagId");

Map<String,AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":column_search",new AttributeValue().withS(query));

QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
  .withTableName(dynamoDbTableName)
  .withKeyConditionExpression("#tagId = :column_search") 
  .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
  .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
  .withLimit(page_limit)
  .withExclusiveStartKey(mapLastEvaluatedKey);

System.out.println(" queryRequest " + queryRequest  );

QueryResult queryResult = client.query(queryRequest);

Map<String, AttributeValue> mapLastEvaluatedKeyReturned = null;
mapLastEvaluatedKeyReturned = queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();


  error -->{ "timestamp": "2019-06-04T19:58:18.156+0000", "status": 500, 
  "error": "Internal Server Error", "exception": 
   "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException", 
   "message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is 
    com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: 
    Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 
    400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 
    BRCI1FLM3375SB8U6JSJEAH09NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)", "path": 
     "/api/v1/metadata/tag/tagIdPage/military_status/page/1/limit/2" }
```

This is the system.out of the queryRequest and sent to the DB

```
  queryRequest {TableName: tagMetadata_Certified-dev,Limit: 
   2,FilterExpression: tagId = :tagIdValue,KeyConditionExpression: #tagId = :tagIdValue,ExpressionAttributeNames: 
   {#tagId=tagId},ExpressionAttributeValues: {:tagIdValue={S: 
   military_status,}}}
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks 
Phil

Comment: I dont get the part where you put tag but you basically look like you want to get data from a dynamodb table right ?

Comment: This is a for a Rest api GET.. the output from above system.out is :  queryRequest {TableName: tagMetadata_Certified-dev,Limit: 1,KeyConditions: {tagId={AttributeValueList: [{S: military_status,}],ComparisonOperator: EQ}},}

Comment: Does this look correct to send to Dynamodb? I check the 400 error and its a general one stating there is an issue with columns sent or formatting..

Comment: error -->{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-04T19:58:18.156+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException",
    "message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: BRCI1FLM3375SB8U6JSJEAH09NVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)",
    "path": "/api/v1/metadata/tag/tagIdPage/military_status/page/1/limit/2"
}

Comment: I have a working script that takes data from dynamodb, may be you  can use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issued using the aws cli from the terminal window. This is very useful for testing with the --debug switch.

Scroll right for full code...

```
 aws dynamodb query --table-name tableNameHere  --region regionNameHere --key-condition-expression "tagId = :tagIdValue"  --filter-expression "isReportable = :p" --expression-attribute-values '{":tagIdValue":{"S":"m_status"}, ":p":{"BOOL":true}}' --debug



public String getRequestPage(String tagIdPassed,  String lastEvaluatedKey, String limit) {
.... code removed ...

Boolean isReportableBool = true;

TagMetadata tagMetadata = new TagMetadata();

Map<String,String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributesNames.put("#tagId","tagId");
expressionAttributesNames.put("#isReportable","isReportable");

Map<String,AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":tagIdValue",new AttributeValue().withS(tagIdPassed));
expressionAttributeValues.put(":isReportableValue",new AttributeValue().withBOOL(isReportableBool));

QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
  .withTableName(dynamoDbTableName)
  .withKeyConditionExpression("#tagId = :tagIdValue")
  .withFilterExpression("#isReportable = :isReportableValue")
  .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
  .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
  .withLimit(page_limit);
```